# when using RobustScaler should you transform y train?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am using RobustScaler to fit and transform x_train and x_test. Should i also transform
y_train and y_test as well. I was thinking this because neural net gives weird val loss.
Sometimes val loss is small and good but sometimes its high and bad maybe its just initialized weights
of neural net but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't. You should scale your Xs because otherwise you neural network can start thinking some of the features are more usefull only because too big values.

y - is the result. Scaling it - is pointless activity. Neural networks can produce big numbers.

Actually, NNs can process big values, when all features have the same "weight". Using scalers is just a good practice.